# what resources are shared and what are created during new process and new thread creation in linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process

what (1>resources are shared) and what (2>resources are created new)  during (1>new process) and (2>new thread) creation in linux?
I searched for it, but nowhere it is mentioned what resources are created new and what are shared

Answer (score 2):

When you call fork() and create a child, all descriptors open in the parent before the call to fork are **shared** between the parent and the child. For instance a socket in parent and say the parent calls accept and then calls fork. The connected socket is then shared between the parent and the child. Normally, the child then reads and writes the connected socket and the parent closes the connected socket.

In the traditional UNIX model, when a parent process needs something performed by another entity, it forks a child process and lets the child perform the processing. While this paradigm has served well for many years there are issues as well:

1. fork is *expensive*. Memory is copied from the parent to the child, all descriptors are duplicated in the child and so on. Some optimizations have been made in recent days with *copy-on-write*, which avoids copy until the child needs its own copy.
2. While passing information from parent to child is easy, the reverse takes some work. And in order to achieve the pass information IPC (Inter Process Communication) is required.

So LINUX introduced clone(). clone() allows the child process to share parts of its execution context with the calling process, such as the memory space, the table of file descriptors, and the table of signal handlers.

Then comes the **threads**. They are also known as *lightweight processes*. Thread creation can be 10-100 times faster than process creation as you can guess. All threads within a process share the same global memory. This makes the sharing of information easy between threads, but along with this comes the requirement to synchronize access.

To sum up, all threads share the following:

- Process information
- Most Data
- Open files (eg descriptors)
- Signal Handlers
- Current working dir
- user and group ids

But each thread has its own:

- ThreadID
- set of registers
- stack for local variables and return addresses
- errno
- signal mask
- priority